# PHP un-editable pdf/file export option

Tags: php, pdf, export, kohana

I am developing an application in the Kohana PHP framework that assesses performance. The end result of the process is a webpage listing the overall scoring and a color coded list of divs and results.

The original idea was to have the option to save this as a non-editable PDF file and email the user. After further research I have found this to be non as straight forward as I hoped.

The best solution seemed to be installing the unix application [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) but as the destination is shared hosting I am unable to install this on the server.

My question is, what's the best option to save a non editable review of the assessment to the user?

Thank you for help with this.

Comment: Why should a pdf be not editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a PHP version that is pre-built as a Kohana Module - github.com/ryross/pdfview

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to generate a snapshot, or review how you call it, is by storing it on the server side and only grant access via a read only protocol. So basically by offering it as a 'web page'.

Still everyone can save and modify the markup. But that is the case for every file you generate, regardless of the type of file. Ok, maybe except DRM infected files. But you don't want to do that, trust me.

Oh, and you could also print the files. Printouts are pretty hard to be edited. Though even that is not impossible...